# Get active tooltip's text in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I'm looking for a way to get content (text) of the active tooltip on a Leaflet map.
I can bind new tooltip content, but I can't seem to find a method to get the text.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to identify an object that the user hovers over to trigger an additional action outside of Leaflet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Tooltip content with: `marker.getTooltip().getContent();`